# delete duplicate row based on the column values in sql

Tags: sql

I have a test data like below

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
----------------------------    
1      a      b     d    c
1      a      b     c    d
2      p      q     r    s
2      p      q     s    r
2      p      q     t    u    
2      p      q     u    t
```

Col4 and col5 are much more similar and col5 is an alternate value of col4.

As I have 2 rows I want to delete the one

I want only one row from the (1st and 2nd) rows and one row from the (3rd and 4th)and one row from (5th and 6th).

Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server/MySQL/Firebird?

Comment: THose four rows are all **distinct** - no duplication ....

Comment: no duplicates and it is in sql

Comment: There are no duplicates in your sample data and SQL is a query language not a DBMS product. Every relational database uses SQL.

Comment: And which rows do you want to keep then?

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate on your requirements a bit more clearly. For example, what would happen if row 2 looked like `2 | b | a | c | d`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove "duplicates" based on the values in the columns `col2` and `col3`? Not the entire row?

Comment: no change in the data.

Comment: I guess OP want to sort each column and get ditstinct rows `1(abdc) and 2(abcd)` after sorting `1(abcd) and 2(abcd)` duplicates for OP. The same for 3 and 4.

Comment: but col4 and col5 has distinct value..on which bases u want to select?

Comment: OK, so if `col2` and `col3` are the same in two rows, you consider the rows identical? What if you had `2 | a | b | c | f`?

Comment: what values are stored at col4 & col5 ?? numeric values? which one would you like to keep? the minimal? the shortest string? you can build an appropriate expression accordingly....

Comment: How do you decide which rows to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `row_number() over(partition by col2,col3 order by col1)` we are saving the row numbers and deleting the rows having `row number >1` will remove the duplicates.